# Python: Finding and changing elements in fixed length records

Tags: python, fixed-length-record

I am very new to programming, and have hit a wall with file handling this week.  I have the following prompt:

> Fixed Length Records
>
> You will be passed the filename P, firstname F,
>   lastname L, and a new birthday B.
>
> Load the fixed length record file in P, search for F,L in the first
>   and change birthday to B.
>
> Then save the file.

The inputs are provided:

```
import sys
P= sys.argv[1] 
F= sys.argv[2]
L= sys.argv[3]
B= sys.argv[4]
```

My Code:

```
file1 = open(P, 'r')

data = file1.read()


for i in range(0, len(data)):
  if F and L not in data: 
    data.append(i)
  if F and L in data: 
    data.replace(B,B)


file1 = open(P, 'w')
file1.write(data)
file1.close()
```

This is obviously not working, but I am spinning wheels.  I need to figure out how to change B, but can't quite get there.  This is the output:

> Program Output
>
> Your program output did not match the expected output.
>
> Your output:
>
> Adam            Smith           11111985Theodore Anderson
>   03201990Monty           Biscuit-Barrel  10181980Adam   Smithers
>   10101960Ruthy           Anderson        06062010
>
> Expected output:
>
> Adam            Smith           11111985Theodore Anderson
>   03201990Monty          Biscuit-Barrel 10181980Adam     Smithers
>   00000000Ruthy          Anderson        06062010

I can't figure out how to change the birthday to B.

Comment: Give me some sample test data.

Comment: Are you sure you have formatted the expected output correctly here? The Records are not on different lines, making it hard to help.

Comment: I edited the format so they now match.  I can't figure out how to replace the birthday with B.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it in the Codio challenge and it did pass the check

```
import re #import regular expressions. Put under the "import sys"

file1 = open(P, 'r') 
data = file1.read() 
file1.close() 


found = re.findall(F + ' *' + L + ' *', data) 
chars = len(found[0])

beginChar = data.find(found[0])
birthday = data[beginChar + chars:beginChar + chars + 8]
data = data.replace(birthday, B)

file1 = open(P, 'w')
file1.write(data)

file1.close
```

Hope this helps out!

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we could see the arguments being passed to the program. 
Also, in your loop, when you are testing for:
`if F and L not in data`
You're actually saying:
`if F != None and L not in data`
Try this instead:
`if F not in data and L not in data`

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be one problem: `data.replace(B,B)`
What does it mean to replace `B` with `B`?

Also, what is `data.append(i)` doing? You are adding an integer at the end of the data you read? I don't understand.

I would like to help out but I don't understand what you are doing. If you have posted the code somewhere online and comfortable sharing it, send a link to it. Also as I requested, you need to share with us the file that you are reading, and some sample data that is being passed in, so we can see whats happening.